# Index binary type of a number

Tags: python, binary

```
b'1'[0]
```

The binary sequence of 1, when indexed is 49, I can't figure out why is it. Also the b'2'[0] is 50, what is the underlying binary sequence for the numbers?

Comment: Look up ASCII/Unicode codes.

Comment: Because `ord('1')` is `49`.  Likewise, `chr(49)` is `'1'`.  There's a difference between characters (in a string) and integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is no a "binary sequence", it is a `bytes` literal.

```
>>> type(b'1')
<class 'bytes'>
```

A [`bytes` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) is an immutable sequence of single bytes, so all numbers in this sequence have to be in range(0, 256)`. You can construct it from a list of numbers as well:

```
>>> bytes([50, 33])     
b'2!'
```

So what is this `b''` notation all about?

Well, sequences of bytes are often related to text. Not always, but often enough that Python supports a lot of string methods on bytes objects, like `capitalize`, `index` and `split`, as well as this convenient literal syntax where you can enter text, and have it be equivalent to series of bytes corresponding to that text encoded in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). It's still an immutable sequence of numbers in `range(0, 256)` under the hood, though, which is why indexing a `bytes` object gives a number.